# ADF: How do I clear a table in SQL?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that ingests data from Kusto, does some simple transformation, and flows the data to SQL. It will be run once per day, and needs to clear the sink tables in SQL. I thought this would be straightforward (and probably is) but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Are you using a Copy activity?  If so, it as a 'Pre-copy script' section in the SQL sink where you can enter SQL like `TRUNCATE TABLE yourTableName` for example.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Works like a charm, thanks @wBob!

Comment: Hi@Easy Rhino You also can post it as answer and mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @wBob said, if you are using Copy activity in ADF, we can enter `TRUNCATE TABLE <your-table-name>` at Pre-copy script. It will execute the T-SQL script here before copying.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a stored procedure on prior to transformation, which can delete your staging data.
Stored procedure->do transformation